# MySQL PHP display all messages in conversation grouped by parent records

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mysqli_fetch_assoc to echo out results of a query to my page.  Unfortunately, it's giving me a 1 to 1 relationship.

Here is how they are displaying currently:

```
Listing Name    Thread ID   Guest Name  Sent by UserID  Message     
Spacious Bedroom    338082922   Daniel  43762688    I can't, I'm sorry. I won't even be around at the end of July.  
Spacious Bedroom    338082922   Daniel  98936811    Are you willing to rent it out at the end of july   
Spacious Bedroom    338082922   Daniel  43762688    Sorry, no room  
Spacious Bedroom    338082922   Daniel  98936811    Hello, I'd like to stay Thanks -Dan
```

I'd like to display the Listing Name once, the Thread ID once, the Guest Name once and then display the conversation between the two users next to that.

I want the conversation to be grouped under the Listing, thread and guest.

Here is what I am currently doing that is not getting me the desired result:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: left; width: 300px;">Listing Name</th>
        <th style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Thread ID</th>
        <th style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Guest Name</th>
        <th style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Sent by User ID</th>
        <th style="text-align: left; width: 300px;">Message</th>
      </tr>
            <?php while($message = mysqli_fetch_assoc($message_set)) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($message["listingname"]); ?></td><td><?php echo htmlentities($message["thread_id"]); ?></td><td><?php echo htmlentities($message["guest_name"]); ?></td><td><?php echo htmlentities($message["sent_by"]); ?></td><td><?php echo htmlentities($message["msg_body"]); ?></td>
      </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: I would probably design the tables a bit differently, so that the messages are in a separate table with `Thread ID` as foreign key. Maybe even three tables, if one Listing can have several Threads. So: Listings, Threads and Messages. Then you could grab the Thread (and Listing) once, and then all Messages for that particular Thread.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use either a nested loop or join the table to itself using mysql?

Comment: You could loop over the results and store the Messages in an array, and then display the content of that array eventually (together with the Listing Name etc. from the first result row, if these are identical all the way through)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to track the current listing name. If it changes, print it, else print nothing. Here is the logic:

```
$name='';
…
if($message["listingname"]==$name) echo '';
else echo $name=$message["listingname"];
```

Here, we

- initialise the variable to `''`
- if the new name matches, echo `''`
- else echo the new name.

The `echo $a=$b` construct copies $b int $a and then prints the result.

Comment: But the thread ID can change within each Listing Name.  In other words, each listing can have many threads and each thread can have many messages